# Задать фон для MKPolygonRenderer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

Имеется карта на которую нанесены `MKPolygonRenderer`,
Необходимо сделать, вью которое будет накладываться на карту, но не будет скрывать `MKPolygonRenderer`, (грубо говоря фон для `MKPolygonRenderer`)
Для примера выделить все страны Европы зеленым цветом, а всю остальную карту залить синим цветом. 
Сейчас выглядит вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: Простите за плохое описание проблемы, постарался объяснить проблему более развернуто.

Comment: то есть, есть вью, который надо вставить между картой и полигонами?

Comment: Да, именно, я думаю надо просто сделать полигон размером на всю карту, и поставит его первым, но нужно найти координаты...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, была найдена библиотека https://github.com/lukya/MKMapDimOverlay.
Которая создает оверлэй размером во всю карту.